# Blobfuse out of memory when copying single 100GB file from mounted storage to host filesystem

Tags: azure-blob-storage, ubuntu-18.04

I have mounted an azure storage account Azure VM (ubuntu 18.04). Mount point is in 4TB vHDD with 2TB ram disk for blobfuse (1.4.2.). In storage account I have 16 pieces of 100GB zipped files which I am trying to copy to VM filesystem but get an error:

**cp: cannot open './datafile.bz2.partaq' for reading: Software caused connection abort**

**cp: cannot open './datafile.bz2.partaq' for reading: Transport endpoint is not connected**

syslog:

```
Dec 23 14:01:00 backupVM  kernel: [1694861.841872] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/user.slice,task=blobfuse,p
id=26036,uid=0
Dec 23 14:01:00 backupVM kernel: [1694861.841896] Out of memory: Killed process 26036 (blobfuse) total-vm:421240kB, anon-rss:156972kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:0 pgtab
les:588kB oom_score_adj:0
Dec 23 14:01:00 backupVM  kernel: [1694861.865857] oom_reaper: reaped process 26036 (blobfuse), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

Copying 2GB file works fine. VM has 14GB RAM. Any hints?

Comment: Hello @Maros, If my answer is helpful for you, you can Upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don’t have large file data so I cannot test. But I have tested with approx. 2GB+ file and it is working fine for me.

What I have did is uploaded around 2GB+ files of data in Azure Blob storage and mount the container in Linux Machine using the blob fuse. Converted the mounted file in tar file and copied in my VM machine file system.

[image]

[image]

Error : 'Software caused connection abort 'generally comes for the disconnection between copying the large file. So instead of using cp command .
you could copy the files with the nohup command. This would keep the copy process alive even if you get disconnected.
To synchronize your source and destination directory using rsync, you could use

```
nohup rsync -av /path_to/source_directory/ /path_to/destination_directory
```

This would copy all remaining files and directories (if any) from the source to the destination directory and would also make sure that no "partly" copied files are left in the destination directory.
Another possibility to check if both directories contain the same files is the use of diff:

```
# compare dirs and watch result in terminal
diff -r /path_to/source_directory /path_to/destination_directory
# compare dirs and write result to diff.log (disconnection failsafe)
nohup diff -r /path_to/source_directory /path_to/destination_directory > diff.log
```

&
The second command would create a logfile diff.log of all files only existing in one of both directories as well as all files with differences (partly copied) and thus help you find out at which point the copy process was aborted.

Note : Make sure you add the trailing slash `"/"` to the source directory, otherwise you will copy your source directory as subdirectory to the destination dir. If you previously did a `cp -r /home/user/dir1 /tmp/dir2` you will need `rsync -av /home/user/dir1/ /tmp/dir2`

Reference : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/497738/network-error-software-caused-connection-abort-during-copying-on-linux